# How to create dynamic Tab menu in java script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create dynamic tab menus using java script. It's easy to create using jquery. But not all mobile devices support jquery. I need the same function in JavaScript.

Comment: What mobile doesn't support jquery? There may be a mobile that jquery doesn't support, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is a JavaScript library and mobile devices support JavaScript. Also, most mobile devices are running a version of WebKit mobile. You can easily build dynamic tabs using jQuery/css3. 
You can also try this framework: http://jquerymobile.com/

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

`<div><div id='T1' onclick='ShowContainer(this);'>Tab 1</div><div id='T2' onclick='ShowContainer(this);'>Tab 2</div></div><div><div id='CT1' class='containers'>Tab Container1</div><div id='CT1' class='containers'>Tab Container 2</div> </div></div>`

`<script> function ShowContainer(obj) { for(var i = 0 ; i < document.getElementsByClassName("containers").length;i++){document.getElementsByClassName("containers")[i].style.display='none' } 
}
document.getElementById('C'+ obj.id).style.display='';
</script>`

Comment: Your coding is good when we know how much tabs @ run time.but i need to generate tabs on user events(lik add tab button on window).User can able to add new tab dynamically.thanks kamelesh..!

Comment: You should specify while posting your question